# how to find the total time taken by a job in oozie

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

Is there a oozie coomandline that I can use or some other way to figure out the start and end time of an oozie jobs submitted through a coordinator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see the start and end time of a cooridnator job

```
$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -info 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe
```

For more info, [For finding the info about workflow,cooridnator and bundle jobs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Checking_the_Status_of_a_Workflow_Coordinator_or_Bundle_Job_or_a_Coordinator_Action)